# classnotfoundexeption : org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.row

Tags: java, excel, apache, maven, netbeans

I am new to Java and I have just developed an application using Netbeans, Maven and Apache POI.

The application reads input from an excel file and generates output in a different excel file.

When I run the application Netbeans everything works fine, however when I try to run the generated jar file, I get the following error

> classnotfoundexeption : org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.row

Comment: You have to include the libraries in the [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) when running your application.

Comment: that where my problem is. I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You use Maven so u need to add in your dependencies the libraries needed.

Like that :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

And u will use this : 
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row

If you want to have your dependencies into your jar file, you need to force the build like that :

```
<!-- Add Shade plugin to include Apache POI dependencies into jar -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas</include>
                                <include>org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml</include>
                                <include>org.apache.poi:poi</include>
                                <include>org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have these dependances in my pom.xml hence the application works in Netbeans. It is the generated jar file that does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have declared the poi and poi-ooxml dependances in my POM.xml hence the application works well in netbeans. problem is that the generated .jar file does not run